# Pasar filas de un JTable a otro. JAVA SWING

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Necesito seleccionar una fila de un jtable y agregarlo a otro. Pero al momento de hacerlo lo hace, pero al hacerlo de nuevo se elimina el que ya habia seleccionado.

```
public void tablaAtabla(){
    int fila = IUPedidosUSER.tableSolicitudes.getSelectedRow();
    String dato = (String) IUPedidosUSER.tableSolicitudes.getValueAt(fila, 1);
    TableModel model = PedidosUSER.tableList.getModel();
    String[] titulos = {"Nombre","Cantidad"};
        Object datos[] = new Object[2];
        llenartabla = new DefaultTableModel (null,titulos);

            datos[0] = dato;
            datos[1] = cantidad.getValue();
            llenartabla.addRow(datos);


        PedidosUSER.tableList.setModel(llenartabla);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773776/how-to-copy-one-row-from-jtable-into-another-jtable, esto le puede ser de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
public void tablaAtabla(){
  int fila = IUPedidosUSER.tableSolicitudes.getSelectedRow();
  String dato = (String) IUPedidosUSER.tableSolicitudes.getValueAt(fila, 1);
  TableModel model = PedidosUSER.tableList.getModel();
  /*
    Aquí tu variable model ya tiene el modelo de la tabla que quieres actualizar.
    Ya no debes volverlo a inicializar a menos que no lo hubieras hecho.
    Agregamos el siguiente if:
  */
  if (model == null) {
     //ok, si no tienes un modelo lo creamos

      String[] titulos = {"Nombre","Cantidad"};
      llenartabla = new DefaultTableModel (null,titulos);
     // y vinculamos el modelo a la tabla:
     PedidosUSER.tableList.setModel(llenartabla);
  }
  //después de esto agregamos el renglón al modelo

  Object datos[] = new Object[2];
  datos[0] = dato;
  datos[1] = cantidad.getValue();
  llenartabla.addRow(datos);

  // Y esta línea de abajo la quitamos porque te está inicializando el modelo
  // y esto solo se requiere hacer una vez
 // PedidosUSER.tableList.setModel(llenartabla);
}
```